# Connect ZTE Android Phone to Linux (Fedora) for USB debugging and file transfer

Tags: udev, android, adb, zte

I just got a new ZTE Phone and I'm trying to connect it to my PC via USB. I'm running Fedora 24 and mostly need to connect the phone for USB file transfer as well as app development using Android Studio.

There is a connection-mode on the phone that says "Install drivers", which displays the phone as a USB drive with a few `.exe` files, but they fail to open/run (I guess they are Windows drivers).

As a next step I tried to add a `udev` rule using the `idVendor` and `idProduct` that were returned by `lsusb` (`19d2:0241`), I set the group to `plugdev` and the mode to `0664`. This still didn't solve the problem (my old phone worked fine after adding an `udev` rule).

`adb devices` returns `a0b14f8b no permissions`. I'm a bit puzzled as to where to find the appropriate drivers and make the USB connection work.
Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: the exact model of the Phone is ZTE Axon Elite Gold 5.5inch 32GB

Answer (score 2):

Turn on Developer Option:

```
First, open up your Settings app.
Scroll all the way down to find “About phone” (or “About Tablet”)
Scroll down again and find the entry with the Build number.
Start tapping on the “Build number section”, Android will now pop up a message informing you that in x amount of clicks you will become a Developer. Keep tapping until the process is complete.
```

Once you got it turn on USB Debugging. Switch to MTP mode and you should accept the fingerprint of certificate on your android device. 
Cheers

Comment: Good stuff, MTP did the job, thx!